# multiple pg_dump

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

My Postgres 9.3 cluster has 9 databases. I want to take backup of these databases using `pg_dump` utility of PostgreSQL 10.

Since individual dbs are too large in size (~350GB), I want to run `pg_dump` for at least 3 dbs simultaneously in order to save time. Then again for another 3 and so on.

Also, I have to take backup of entire cluster (as per my client requirement) using `pg_basebackup`.

So can I run 3 `pg_dump` instances and one `pg_basebackup` simultaneously? Is this the right approach?

Comment: Yes, you can run all those simultaneously - but if unless you have really fast  harddisks, this might actually be slower than running one after the other.

Comment: Thanks. One thing I forgot to mention. I have 2 streaming replication for this cluster on other servers. What if I run `pg_basebackup` and `pg_dump` on master and another `pg_dump` on slave servers. I need suggestion.

Comment: Sure, all that is possible. You can have a standby just for taking backups. If I were you, I wouldn't run `pg_dump` at all if you have a backup anyway.

Comment: Thanks @LaurenzAlbe